# Pushstate/popstate javascript browser back button to work with a non-linear slideshow/carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just starting to learn javascript. I have a slideshow that I've made. I'm trying to get the browser back button to work with it. I can't just do the normal current div -1 approach because it's a non-linear slideshow; You can arrive at any slide from any slide. I can't predefine all the slides in the javascript either because I'll be adding a lot more slides in later. I know I have to use PushState() and PopState() but I can't get them working with my setup.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  if (isNaN(n)) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var found = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      if (slides[i].getAttribute("name") == n) {
        found = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) return;
    n = found;
  }
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}
 
function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
} 

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " opacity-off";
}
```

```css
.mainstyle {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    background: repeating-radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50) 70.3%, rgba(243, 243, 243, 00) 100%);
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.main-content {
    margin: auto
}
.opacity,
.hover-opacity:hover {
    opacity: 0.60;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
}
.opacity-off,
.hover-opacity-off:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<!-- slideone -->
<div class="main-content" style="max-width:1200px">
  <p name="slideone" class="mySlides"><span style=font-size:18px><strong>slideone</span></strong><br>&nbsp;<br><span id="slideone">1La so ray teela mee latee, la so ray meela</span>
      <br>&nbsp;<br>
      <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slideone')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidetwo')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidethree')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefour')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png" style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefive')">
  </p>
  
  <!-- slidetwo -->
  <p name="slidetwo" class="mySlides"><span style=font-size:18px><strong>slidetwo</span></strong><br>&nbsp;<br><span id="slidetwo">2La so ray teela mee latee, la so ray meela</span>
      <br>&nbsp;<br>
      <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slideone')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidetwo')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidethree')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefour')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png" style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefive')">
      </br>
  </p>
  
  <!-- slidethree -->
   <p name="slidethree" class="mySlides"><span style=font-size:18px><strong>slidethree</span></strong><br>&nbsp;<br><span id="slidethree">3La so ray teela mee latee, la so ray meela</span>
      <br>&nbsp;<br>
      <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slideone')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidetwo')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidethree')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefour')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png" style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefive')">
      </br>
  </p>

</div>
 
  <!-- slidefour -->
   <p name="slidefour" class="mySlides"><span style=font-size:18px><strong>slidefour</span></strong><br>&nbsp;<br><span id="slidefour">4La so ray teela mee latee, la so ray meela</span>
      <br>&nbsp;<br>
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slideone')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidetwo')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidethree')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefour')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png" style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefive')">
  </p>
  
  <!--slidefive -->
  <p name="slidefive" class="mySlides"><span style=font-size:18px><strong>slidefive</span></strong><br>&nbsp;<br><span id="slidefive">5La so ray teela mee latee, la so ray meela</span>
      <br>&nbsp;<br>
    <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slideone')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidetwo')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidethree')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png"  style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefour')">&nbsp; &nbsp;
     <img class="opacity hover-opacity-off" src="http://fs.datafrenzy.com/images/buttons/add-circle.png" style=padding:5px onclick="currentDiv('slidefive')">
  </p> 
</div>
```